# When to use conditional probability?

Tags: probability

> In a certain startup company, the managers are looking for employees for two types of
> positions - A and B. The examination process of the applicants consists
> of two stages. The first stage consists of two tests. Test A tests
> suitability for position A and test B tests suitability for position
> B. An applicant who successfully passes at least one of the two tests
> in the first stage is invited to the second stage, which consists of
> one test. An applicant who has successfully passed the test suitable
> for the position in the first stage and the test in the second stage
> is defined as suitable for the position. The following data are known:
> the probability that an applicant will be defined as suitable for both
> positions is 0.2. The probability that an applicant will be invited to
> the second stage is 0.85. The probability that an applicant will
> successfully pass test A is 0.3. The probability that an applicant
> will successfully pass test B is 0.7 and the probability that an
> applicant will successfully pass the second stage test is 0.45.

I would define the known probabilities: P(A)=0.3 - pass test A, P(B)=0.7 - pass test B, P(C)=0.45 - pass the final test. We also know that P(A∪B) = 0.85.

We are asked to create a table of amounts of passed tests at stages I and II. For example, in order to find the probability of two successful tests at stage I and successful stage II, I thought that the probability of suitability for positions A and B is P(C|A∩B)=0.2, as given. Since the final test comes after a successful first stage. But the right way to write it in a mathematical way is P(A∩B∩C)=0.2. Here I am confused. Why not to use conditional probability here and use the intersection instead?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems pretty clear to me that the word "applicant" in the statement "the probability that an applicant will be defined as suitable for both positions is $\ 0.2\ $" refers to an *original* applicant who has yet to sit for any of the tests.
To be suitable for *both* positions, an such an applicant must pass *all three* tests, which is the event $\ C\cap A\cap B\ $, so $\ P(C\cap A\cap B)\ $ is the correct probability for this circumstance.

The conditional probability $\ P(C\,|\ A\cap B)\ $ is merely the probability that an applicant *who has managed to pass* both tests $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ will then go on to pass test $\ C\ $ as well, but since
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)=0.15\ ,$$
that cohort will only be $\ 15\%\ $ of the original applicants.

As described, however, this whole scenario isn't even possible, because it requires
$$
0.15=P(A\cap B)\ge P(C\cap A\cap B)=0.2\ .
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!